# how to set DataContext when mainWindow is null?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
class Program : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {

        Program app = new Program();
        app.StartupUri = new Uri("../../LoginWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

       //app.MainWindow is null
        app.Run();

    }

    virtual protected void OnStartUp(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start up");

    }
}
```

//the MainWindow of app is null, so how can I set the DataContext to the LoginWindow(is an UserControl) in void Main()
//for some reason, there should not be a window class, I  want to directly start the UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not the proper way which a [WPF application starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application) in. I do not know why you need to create a `Main` method as your application were a Windows.Form one. Anyway you can do what you need looking at [this blog](https://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2010/04/20/writing-a-custom-main-method-for-wpf-applications/).

Basically you

> need to change the application's build action from "*Application Definition*" to "*Page*", create a constructor that calls "*InitializeComponent*", and write your Main() by eventually calling one of the application’s "*Run*" method overloads

Then your code will become

```
class Program : Application
{
    public Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        /* Here you can set loginWindow's DataContext */ 
        Program app = new Program();
        app.Run(window);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way to do this is to subscribe to the Startup event of your application:

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="App_Startup" />
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App
{
    private void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = new MainView { DataContext = new MainVM() };
        view.Show();
    }
}
```